# how do i do this in elementor, need to create sorting dropdown that changes a section

Tags: wordpress, elementor

[image]

Hello i need to create a dropdown that changes an entire section of content, anyone know of a elementor plugin that is capable of this?

Answer (score 0):

i tried using Advanced custom fields to create a select box but not sure how to configure this...